# Can ROS be used for making online simulations and remote-triggered experiments

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can ROS be used as platform for creating virtual experiments like simulations, so that users all over the world can access and perform their own experiments by changing parameters

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258415/can-ros-be-used-for-making-online-simulations-and-remote-triggered-experiments/) by [Sharath](https://answers.ros.org/users/29899/sharath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. DARPA did this for the [Virtual Robotics Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DARPA_Robotics_Challenge). Their online simulation was an adaptation of the Gazebo simulator called [DRCsim](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/wiki/Home).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1